# How to fix window.open('http://maps.apple.com/?q=', '_system')?

Tags: ios, ionic4

IONIC 4 - How to fix

```
window.open('http://maps.apple.com/?q=', '_system')
```

does not working in first time in iOS?

I already tried with the following code. But, it's not OK.

```
window.open('maps://?q=', '_system');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the InAppBrowser plugin?

You would install it [as your would for a normal plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser), and then use something like:

```
constructor(
  private iab: InAppBrowser
  ) { }
```

And then for the actual code:

```
let link = 'http://maps.apple.com/?q=';
this.iab.create(link, '_system', 'location=yes');
```